# How to automatically select pre - authorized account in googlesheets4 in R when scheduling code?

Tags: r, google-sheets, token, googlesheets4

I'm trying to figure out what would be the method to automatically allow the googlesheet4 package to choose my pre - authorized account to download a particular google sheet.

For example - I want to run the following once a day -

```
library(googlesheets4)
delta<-read_sheet(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xyz...",
  sheet = "XYZ Delta"
)
```

The console gives the following output:

```
The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account.
Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. 
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort.

1. xyz@gmail.com
```

As can be seen above, I've already given it access to the account to utilize the google sheet in a previous step. But it still asks me to manually enter "1" to choose this account.
Is it possible to automate this so I don't have to manually enter "1" to run this script when I autoschedule this code?

Would be grateful if you could point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call `gs4_auth` before `read_sheet`

```
gs4_auth("xyz@gmail.com")
```