# How to automatically select pre - authorized account in googlesheets4 in R when running automated code?

Tags: r, authentication, automation, authorization, googlesheets4

I'm trying to figure out what would be the method to automatically allow the googlesheet4 package to choose my pre - authorized account to modify a particular google sheet.

For example - I want to run the following once a day -

```
library(googlesheets4)
gs4_auth("xyz@gmail.com")
ss<-sheet_write(table, ss="sheeturl", sheet= "CW24")
```

When I run the code, after gs4_auth() a browser window opens and asks to confirm (manually) that Tidyverse can access to my email.
Would it be possible to pre-authorize my account, so to avoid any manual interference?

I would like to run the code also when my laptop is switched off, so ideally I need to pre-authorize my account in a new session.

A similar question was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464491/how-to-automatically-select-pre-authorized-account-in-googlesheets4-in-r-when), but in the solution proposed here works only in an already existing session: the first time you need to authorize your email manually, then it works automatically with gs4_auth().

In additon, gs4_auth() was modified in the latest googlesheet4 update and now requires to authorize manually your email whenever you run gs4_auth().

I have also looked [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets4/googlesheets4.pdf), [here](https://cemyilmaz185.medium.com/how-to-setup-non-interactive-authentication-with-googlesheets4-package-on-r-a0baa5ff8ab0), [here](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/gs4_auth_configure.html) and in many other pages but I could not solve it.
Thanks in advance for your help!